# biber-Double month entry in greek bibitem

Tags: biber, greek

I am creating the bibliography using `pdflatex`, `biber` and `utf8` encoding. The problem is that the field `month` is displayed twice in the greek entries as the red rectangle shows in the next figure

[image]

Any idea on why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

My code is

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}

@article{citeEnglish,
title = "The 11B(p,a)8Be nuclear reaction and 11B(p,p)11B backscattering cross sections for analytical purposes ",
journal = "Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research Section B: Beam Interactions with Materials and Atoms ",
volume = "143",
number = "3",
pages = "244 - 252",
year = "1998",
note = "",
issn = "0168-583X",
% doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-583X(98)00383-8",
% url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168583X98003838",
author = "M. Mayer and A. Annen and W. Jacob and S. Grigull",
hyphenation={english}
}

@Mastersthesis{citeGreek,
title       = {Μεταπτυχιακή Διπλωματική},
journal     = {Βιβλιοθήκη ΕΜΠ},
year        = {2012},
month       = {Ιούλιος},
author      = {Όνομα Επίθετο},
hyphenation = {Greek}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[style=numeric,bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{testbib.bib}
 \renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\newcommand{\sw}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\sq}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext#1\latintext}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{Κεφάλαιο}
  \section{Ενότητα}
  σδφγηξκλ\cite{citeEnglish}hgfkhgjfkhgfkhg\cite{citeGreek}.
  \section{Ενότητα}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία}
%  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  %\selectlanguage{english}
%   \bibliography{testbib}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the manual, section 2.2.2, the field `month` should contain a numeral, so `month={7}`: “This must be an integer, not an ordinal or a string.”

Comment: @egreg : It's exactly what you mention! Replacing month's name with it's number, it's working! Would you mind posting it as an answer? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of `biblatex`, the field `month` should contain a number, not the month name. From section 2.2.2:

> **month** field (datepart)
>   The publication month. This must be an integer, not an ordinal or a string. Don’t say `month={January}` but `month={1}`. The bibliography style converts this to a language dependent string or ordinal where required. See also `date` as well as §§ 2.3.9 and 2.3.8.

So you should try

```
month = {7},
```